# How to display Google Map in Web Browser without Internet Connection

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, web-applications

I've downloaded the map image files by Google Map Downloader. I'm trying to add the google maps in offline website. I'm not sure how to do this.
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Im sorry to share this but this would not be possible completely. You can try out the static google map API to generate an image of a particular area as per the requirement of yours.

Have a quick look at the official documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

and if it fits your need, you can also use the tool such as https://staticmapmaker.com/google/ to generate the Image URL as per your needs.

Happy coding!